Glossaries in file with multiple sections
I am working on a thesis document in overleaf using a template because I am at the beginning of my Latex journey. This template works with a thesisstyle.sty file with contains the information on the glossary like this:
\ProvidesPackage{thesisstyle} 

\RequirePackage[acronym]{glossaries}

In the main document i combine multiple .tex files like this:
\usepackage{thesisstyle}   % Thesisstyle
\includeonly
{
    sections/abbreviations
    sections/introduction,
    sections/thesisaims,
    sections/materials,
    sections/discussion,
}

\begin{document}
    \include{sections/abbreviations}
    \include{sections/introduction}
    \include{sections/thesisaims}
    \include{sections/materials}
    \include{sections/discussion}
\end{document}

In the introduction i define a acronym
artificial intelligence (\acrshort{ai})

Which was defined in the abbreviations.tex file as
\newacronym{ai}{AI}{Artificial intelligence}

My aim is now to print a glossary that shows all the acronyms from the different sections.
When I use
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

... in the main.tex file or abbreviations.tex file nothing happens.
How could I manage to get the complete glossary from all the subsections?
Help is much appreciated. I deleted much of the thesisstyle.sty and also main.tex file in this post in order to give a better overview in this post. But please tell me if you need more information provided.
Kind regards!

Welcome TeX's universe! Do you see glossaries help in Overleaf? May be help you. In this example use the package glossaries and finally to print use \printglossaries

Thanks for the hint, however I think the documentation does not cover global and local glossaries for a document combining several .tex file like in this case.

I would \input rather than \include the abbreviations file, and load it in the preamble. Do you also have the \makeglossaries command in the file? Are you running the makeglossaries binary?
